# If radio button .is(':checked') - not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

I have a javascript code to show a field when a radio button is check. The code works perfectly, but when I uncheck the radio, the field doesn't hide. It also shows a `<span>` when the radio button is checked, but when it's unchecked, also the span doesn't hide..

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#radiopromo2').live('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#fieldtraining").show();
            $("#radio3").show();
        } else {
            $("#fieldtraining").hide();
            $("#radio3").hide();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

Anyone who can help me? I made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4UH2H/8/

Comment: can you show your HTML markup also?  or maybe even create a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates the issue

Comment: `.live` is deprecated (http://api.jquery.com/live/) Have you tried reworking your code as recommended in the docs?

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` (both jQuery object and checking selector) is probably overkill here. Just use `this.checked` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the more appropriate [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
if($(this).prop('checked')){
```

Or even plain old Javascript (it's way faster):

```
if(this.checked){
```

That always works for me. Also, `.live()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`, and for radio buttons it is better to use `click` instead of `change` because of an older webkit version bug not recognizing onchange properly:

```
$('#radiopromo2').on('click',function(){
```

With these changes you should be golden.

**EDIT**
Based on the [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4UH2H/11/), you're event wasn't fired with the correct selector. Here is the updated stuff:

```
$('input[name="radiotraining"]').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#radiopromo2').prop('checked')) {
        $("#fieldtraining").show();
        $("#radio3").show();
    } else {
        $("#fieldtraining").hide();
        $("#radio3").hide();
    }
});
```

It works! yay! Although looking at your jsFiddle, you really should consider using CSS instead of jQuery for such basic show/hide stuff:

```
#fieldtraining,#radio3 {
    display:none;
}

#radiopromo2:checked + #radio2 > #radio3 {
    display:inline;
}

#radiopromo2:checked ~ #fieldtraining {
    display:block;
}
```

Would work perfectly fine with IE9+ and all real browsers (yay CSS3!), would be way faster than JS, and would work even when greyhairs turn off JS on their browsers. You can save the jQuery for those lame old browsers like IE6. [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UH2H/12/) to show what I mean.

Comment: Okay, so I updated my jQuery.. I changed that `$('#radiopromo2').on('click',function(){` and now it just works normal again, but my problem is still not working.. The field still doesn't hide when I click the other radio button. I also tried `if($(this).prop('checked')){`, this doesn't changes anything..

Comment: and uve done `console.log('checked')` or something to see if its firing? and gotten rid of the `trigger('change')`? because thats unnecessary (and might be causing it to unfire again)

Comment: Where do I need to put `console.log('checked')`? And I removed the `trieer('change')` and it's still the same..

Comment: you have an if/else statement inside the `.on('click')`, just do a `console.log('y');` inside where it should be checked and `console.log('n');` inside where it shouldnt be checked. then check ur debugger (firebug, chrome tools, etc) console for the output to see if either are firing.

Comment: Okay, I made a jsfiddle because I don't know what you mean with firing.. :s [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4UH2H/8/)

Comment: your problem was that the event only fired when the SECOND radiobutton was clicked, hence the input always stayed. i updated your jsFiddle here ->http://jsfiddle.net/4UH2H/9/ and i'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you very much! :)) Just a little note: the jsfiddle is just really the basic.. I just copied the HTML and jQuery and deleted everything that wasn't needed.. So I have CSS, just didn't put it in :).. But just a little note, what if I want to change the input name of one of the radio buttons? Thanks!

Comment: then it would no longer be included in the grouping. you could make it more generic like `input[type="radio"]`, but if you have a ton of radio buttons this could get a bit hectic due to a ton of `else if` logic. my mention of CSS was that you can perform the same operations with CSS3 pseudo-class `:checked`, not even need jQuery (at least, based on the HTML you provided). this will be faster in all respects and not reliant on similar name types. heres a jsFiddle to prove my point -> http://jsfiddle.net/4UH2H/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
the behavior of .is() method in jquery is not as expected.Instead of .is() use .attr():
if($(this).attr("checked") == "checked")){
// code goes here
}
```

Comment: don't use attr() to check the checked property.. see here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/CcD9u/) it shows checked even though it's unchecked - its because attr actually checks the defaultChecked state and not the current state.  use .prop() instead

Comment: np :)  It's all about learning the right way - rather learn now than run into issues later and not know what's going on